# Where-Object filter selection using string array

Tags: powershell

I have a custom object with the Properties: Name, Value and others.

I'm trying to filter using `Where` by the name property, using an array:

```
$NamesToExclude= @('Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4')

$CustomObj | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne $NamesToExclude}
```

This returns all excluded names (and others). I have also tried:

```
{$_.Name -ne $($NamesToExclude)}
```

and tried using the `-notlike` operator. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with `-notin`!

```
$CustomObj | Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $NamesToExclude}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an `[Array]` but are using it like a `[String]`

Instead of `-notlike` or `-ne`, use `-notin`:

```
$CustomObj | Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $NamesToExclude}
```

[about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1) goes into more detail.